# string selected in listview to be used outside of public void onItemClick()

Tags: android, listview, position, global, oncreate

How can i use string selected in ListView outside of onItemClick() method within the same activity:

```
public class MainActivityU2U extends Activity {
public String String1;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

       //some coding to get list view adapters and so on

       listParams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View viewClicked, int position, long id) {                                        

                    String1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                }
            });
        if (String1 =="wtvr"){
          //Do this
        } 
        else {
          //Do that
        }
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'd rather see it the other way round: access finally declared views and members as well as methods within your `OnItemClickListener` in order to process the String.

Comment: Just call a method from within your `OnItemClickListener` - easy as that. BTW don't do this...`if (String1 =="wtvr")` - you can't compare strings in Java using `==` - use the `equals(...)` method instead.

Comment: Yes you are right .equals() must be used. But title of ques is 'string selected in listview to be used outside of public void onItemClick()'

Comment: @UmeshChhabra : Yes, and I also answered that in my comment. I added the bit about not using `==` to compare strings as an extra part of my comment. All the OP has to do in order to use the string outside of the `onItemClick` method is simply call a method in the `Activity` - it's not difficult.

Comment: What method?? you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

you could use a method. E.g.

```
private void processInput(String value) {
   if ("wtvr".equals(value)) {

   } else {

   }
}
```

and from `onItemClick`, use the method like:

```
processInput((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position))
```

Comment: So basically a user selects an item in the listview. Then this item is used in many places in the code (within the same activity) to do different things (like for example create another listview based on the item value)